# Riverpod: How do you manage loading and error states with StateNotifier?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

How to use loading/error states with `StateNotifier` like we do with `FutureProvider` in `Riverpod`?

We can do the same with Provider using setState, var isLoading with ternary operator and didChangeDependencies.

Answer (score 7):

`FutureProvider` works with `AsyncValue`.
You can use `AsyncValue` with a `StateNotifier` too like so:

```
final randomNumberProvider = StateNotifierProvider<RandomNumberNotifier, AsyncValue<int>>((ref) {
  return RandomNumberNotifier();
});

class RandomNumberNotifier extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<int>> {
  RandomNumberNotifier() : super(const AsyncLoading());

  void getNewNumber() async {
    state = const AsyncLoading();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    final number = Random().nextInt(500);
    state = AsyncValue.data(number);
  }
}
```

And it allows you to use the `when` method like so:

```
class Page extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Page({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final randomNumberNotifier = ref.watch(randomNumberProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          final p = ref.read(randomNumberProvider.notifier);
          p.getNewNumber();
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: randomNumberNotifier.when(
          data: (data) {
            return Text(data.toString());
          },
          error: (_, __) {
            return const Text("An error occurred");
          },
          loading: () {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to fetch data from Firebase. How do I put it in state?

Comment: Firestore or Reatime database?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70974541/11452511

Comment: I implemented this method but it stacked at loading how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try pressing the floating action button?